# PowerApps Postgres auto increment ID

Tags: postgresql, powerapps

I got a table of the following form in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE contract (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    start_date date NOT NULL,
    end_date date NOT NULL,
    price float8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT contract_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

In Microsoft Powerapps, I create a `EditForm` to update the table above. For other databases, like MS SQL, I didn't need to supply the `id`, since it's auto increment. But for some reason, PowerApps keeps demanding to fill in the `id` for this table, even though it's auto increment and shouldn't be supplied to Postgres.

Anyone with the same experience with Powerapps in combination with Postgres? Struggling with it for hours...

Comment: What if you define the column as an identity column instead? `id integer not null generated always as identity` Maybe Microsoft doesn't know what a `serial` is? ` Using identity is [preferred over serial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) anyway

Comment: Neither `id integer not null generated always as identity` and `id int generated by default as identity primary key` work. In both cases, PowerApps returns an error, saying I should supply the ID.